# Trigger CSS3 animation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Hello i'm trying to figure out how to trigger a css3 animation with javascript, for some reason my code isnt working...` my jfiddle can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/sean3200/RE6K6/

**CSS:**

```
<style>
#div1
{
position: relative;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin: 50px;
padding:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
perspective:150;
-webkit-perspective:150; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#div2
{
padding:50px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: red;
transform: rotateX(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
</style>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myBtn() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('div1').style.webkitPerspective=500;

}
</script>
```

**HTML Elements:**

```
<button onclick="myBtn()">Move Me</button>
<div id="div1">HELLO</div>
<div id="div2">HELLO</div>
<div id="div3">HELLO</div>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any CSS animation `@keyframes` defined.

Comment: Please don't put your title in all caps.

Comment: Sorry about the caps.. but i shouldnt I be able to have a simple onclick event to animate a CSS3 Perspective without using a keyframe.. take a look at [link]http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trycss3_perspective_inuse.htm there using css3 perspective without any keyframes, so there has to be a way to have simple onclick to do this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest your divs for perspective to work:

```
<div id="div1">HELLO</div>
<div id="div2">HELLO</div>
```

Needs to be:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Also, run your js in the head not onload for your fiddle to acknowledge your click event:

http://jsfiddle.net/RE6K6/2/

Comment: Thanks so much Alien!! so for every CSS3 div to work, It has to be nested?? (keyframes, transforms, animations etc..)

Comment: No, but that's how the perspective works. It's the rotation of `div2` inside the perspective of `div1` that gives the effect you want.